# Can I make a type for the positive float in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

My question is about Erlang Type Language.
Can I make a type for the positive float in Erlang?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At this time you can't, you can't even define a type for a single floating point number (i.e. `-type one() :: 1.0.`).

On the other hand, though probably really complex to implement, this seems like a good idea.

You may consider creating a new EEP at https://github.com/erlang/eep

Or opening an issue at http://bugs.erlang.org/

Or even better, if you're up for the challenge, sending a PR to https://github.com/erlang/otp.

If you do any of the above, don't forget to allow for the same degree of liberty to `number()` types ;)